# MpichCluster and R

Tags: r, parallels, cluster

i'm new in parallel computing, 
i need to use all CPU's resources from n desktop computers to execute an operation with R.

I was seeing this documentation
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster

my question is: after i have made up the cluster, i can execute an R script on all computers without any kind of operation such as happens in mapreduce of hadoop??

What i means is that i can execute an R script from a bash and then computing is manage in all the cluster

Answer (score 0):

To run a command over multiple processors in a cluster, you would typically use a command like mpirun, which allocates multiple processors to a single parallel task. For example, the command mpirun -np 4 /home/foo/R would run the R command on 4 processors.

Comment: i can execute any R script without organize it in a kind of way like map and reduce?